# Parsing a RFC822 attachment with email library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the same issue as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924767/python-email-library-parsing-message-rfc822-attachments). An email has an attachment that is message/rfc822 and I am trying to get the content and subject of that attachment.

My code is as follows:

```
with open("raw_email_message", 'rb') as message:
    mime_email_content  = email.message_from_binary_file(message, policy=policy.default)

    for part in mime_email_content.walk():
        if "attachment" not in str(part.get("Content-Disposition")):
            continue

        if part.get("Content-Type").startswith("message/"):
            part_contents = part.as_string()
            for header in part._payload[0]._headers:
                if header[0] == "Subject":
                    filename = header[1]
        else:
            part_contents = part.get_payload(decode=True)
            filename = part.get_filename()
```

part.as_string() gives too much information, whereas only the body and standard headers, such as To and FROM, are needed. I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution for getting the message and any headers.
Ultimately, I need to create a text file from the attachment and save it as its own file.

Answer (score 1):

I realized the best way to handle this situation, and maybe the only way, is to treat the attachment just like the original message and call walk() again, like this:

```
    for part in self.mime_email_content.walk():
        if "attachment" not in str(part.get("Content-Disposition")):
            continue

        if part.get("Content-Type").startswith("message/"):
            for item in part.walk():
                (do work here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Walking by rfc822 attachments recursive way:

```
import email
from email.header import decode_header


def readable_header(h):
    raw_header = decode_header(h)
    header = []
    for part, encoding in raw_header:
        if type(part) == bytes:
            header.append(part.decode(encoding) if encoding is not None else part.decode('ascii'))
        else:
            header.append(part)
    return header

def on_file_found(part):
    filename = readable_header(part.get_filename())
    part_contents = part.get_payload(decode=True)
    print('Attached file', filename, len(part_contents), 'bytes')
        
def on_message_found(content):
    print('Subject:', readable_header(content['Subject']))
    print('From:', readable_header(content['From']))
    print('To:', readable_header(content['To']))
    for part in content.walk():
        if "attachment" in str(part.get("Content-Disposition")):
            on_file_found(part)
        if part.get("Content-Type") == "message/rfc822":
            for payload in part.get_payload():
                on_message_found(email.message_from_bytes(payload.as_bytes()))

with open("test.txt", 'rb') as message:
    on_message_found(email.message_from_binary_file(message))
```

Method `readable_header` returns a list because some headed have a multiple field.

Comment: This solution is what I currently have, and it works fine so long as the attachment's content type is not "message/*". In my case, it is "message/rfc822".

Comment: Could you share example of message with such header?

Comment: I would have to do a lot of sanitizing to the email in order to share it. But I was easily able to reproduce the problem by creating a new email and just drag and drop any previous email in my inbox as an attachment. Then when calling walk() and you get to the attachment that is the email, part.get_payload(decode=True) would fail.

Comment: I've make some rfc822 messages and change answer for recursive messages processing.